# Flask Problem sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table:

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting a **column not found error** with flask, but data and columns appear in sqlite, [image of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC2lI.png):

I got error code :

```
def plot_vends():
    return jsonify([[product, timestamp] for product, timestamp in Vend.query.with_entities(Vend.product, Vend.timestamp).all()])
```

and route

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', products=plot_vends())
```

The code that creates the database:

```
class Vend(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)    
    user =  db.Column(db.String(64))
    product = db.Column(db.String(64))
    price = db.Column(db.Integer())
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime()) 

    def __init__(self, user, product, price, timestamp):
        self.user = user
        self.product = product
        self.price = price
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Vend ('%s','%s','%s','%s')>" % (self.user, self.product, self.price, self.timestamp)
```

I couldn't find a topic about the solution of the error, I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. How do you open the database? When do you create the tables?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.